# Not assigning new data in object

Tags: node.js, express

```
   const data = await subStaffModel.find({ subStaffType: 3 });
   data.map((entry, index) => {
    entry.myName = "rabbani"
    console.log(entry, 'entity', index);
});
console.log(data)
```

I am getting data from substuffMoel.Now I want to add an entity in every object in the data array. I have tried by the above way but it is not woring.

Comment: If you want to store data in database then use insert with specific filter like substafftype:3. If you want to keep the updated data in memory, then store the return value of data.map() in another variable or in data because map returns a new array; it doesn't modify anything.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? the data array is changed.

Comment: I mean data array is not changing. In data arrays object is not adding the ned field myName.@RaniSharim